Drop Down Menu with search bar issue
I'm currently using Flutter version 3.22.2.
For this query, I have used a package dropdown_button2 version 2.3.9
As seen in the 2 images attached, when I click on the search bar of the drop down menu and the keyboard pops up, the screen goes up but the drop down part stays where it is. How can I resolve this?


Following is the code for the search bar with drop down menu, I have written is seperately:
import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DropDownSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropDownSearch({super.key});

  @override
  State<DropDownSearch> createState() => _DropDownSearchState();
}

class _DropDownSearchState extends State<DropDownSearch> {
  final List<String> items = [
    'A_Item1',
    'A_Item2',
    'A_Item3',
  ];

  String? selectedValue;
  final TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton2<String>(
        isExpanded: true,
        hint: Center(
          child: Text(
            '--Select EndUser--',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              color: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .hintColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        items: items
            .map((item) =>
            DropdownMenuItem(
              value: item,
              child: Text(
                item,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
            ))
            .toList(),
        value: selectedValue,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            selectedValue = value;
          });
        },
        buttonStyleData: ButtonStyleData(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            height: 50,
            width: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            )),
        dropdownStyleData: const DropdownStyleData(
          maxHeight: 200,
        ),
        menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
          height: 40,
        ),
        dropdownSearchData: DropdownSearchData(
          searchController: textEditingController,
          searchInnerWidgetHeight: 50,
          searchInnerWidget: Container(
            height: 50,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 8,
              bottom: 4,
              right: 8,
              left: 8,
            ),
            child: TextFormField(
              expands: true,
              maxLines: null,
              controller: textEditingController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10,
                  vertical: 8,
                ),
                hintText: 'Search for an item...',
                hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          searchMatchFn: (item, searchValue) {
            return item.value.toString().contains(searchValue);
          },
        ),
        //This to clear the search value when you close the menu
        onMenuStateChange: (isOpen) {
          if (!isOpen) {
            textEditingController.clear();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Following is the code for the textfield search bar:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SerialSearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const SerialSearchBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<SerialSearchBar> createState() => _SerialSearchBarState();
}

class _SerialSearchBarState extends State<SerialSearchBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 300,
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 10,
            horizontal: 10,
          ),
          hintText: "Serial Number",
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius:
            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The above two codes were implemented into the following code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tpmguru/ticketing/open_ticket/pre_amc_ticket.dart';
import 'main_page_components/drop_down_search.dart';
import 'main_page_components/serial_search_bar.dart';

class OpenTicket extends StatefulWidget {
  const OpenTicket({super.key});

  @override
  State<OpenTicket> createState() => _OpenTicketState();
}

class _OpenTicketState extends State<OpenTicket> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            DropDownSearch(),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text("Or"),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            SerialSearchBar(),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text("Or"),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
                child: Text(
                  "Open Pre AMC Ticket",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> PreAmcTicket())
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I tried your code, and it is working fine, the dropdown is going up with rest of the UI when keyboard opens and also comes back down when keyboard closes. I see no issue in this code.
PS : I tried with same flutter version and same dropdown_button2 package version.

@MayurGadhiya Do you think it could be an emulator thing?

@ Asim Reyazuddin , Might be. You can try creating new emulator.

Try to wrap Dropdown menu with Listener, and give onPointerDown: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus().
